# Possible to display more than 6 items in a menu without the "More" option?

Tags: android, menu

I want to add around 9 options to my menu but I would like all 9 options to show at once. Is there a way i can disable the grouping of the last options into the "More" submenu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Especially on the smaller screens. On the G1 type devices, there is no way 9 menu items would fit without covering the entire screen. And not to mention landscape mode, 9 items would not fit at all.

Maybe create a context menu, then you can have many items and the user would be able to scroll through them if the all didn't fit on the screen.

Comment: Hmm well i was trying to get a "covering the whole screen" kind of effect. I was planning to keep the app in portrait so I don't have to worry about fitting in landscape. I currently have the HTC Eris (which has one of the smaller screen sizes, no?) and I feel that 9 menu items would fit. Either way though, putting all this aside, Android gives me no way of doing this?

Comment: There is no way that I am aware of. you have to take in to account, android is meant for many different types of devices, and some devices, like the nook i believe, has an even smaller screen. So the developers picked a number that would work on all the devices' across the board.